# What is safe implementation for sensitive data file file_url in Django

Tags: django, file, authentication, django-models, download

I am providing sensitive username and password file to the authenticated user. I want user to download the file via file_url in template through model.

```
File_link = models.FileField(upload_to='SAFE_DIRECTORY_PATH')
```

I don't feel it safe storing it in media directory
Any suggestions keeping them safe ,web app will be generating the link.

Comment: What's the point? Passwords aren't stored in plain text: they're hashed.

Comment: @xyres Yes the password is hashed

Comment: That is what I meant. What is the point of letting users download their passwords when they are hashed? Anyways, if you really want to do that, generate the file *on the fly*.

Comment: Seriously? Since when are hashes being *decrypted*? Hashes are irreversible, dude. And you're clearly missing my point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some security notes first.

This is probably a **bad** idea. Storing sensitive information in plain files is probably not the correct security approach, especially if you plan to use Django's media storage backend for doing that. It leaves all files out-in-the-open.

If however you really, really, and I mean **really** need to do that, you should encrypt the file first before saving in Django.

Again though, if at all possible I would recommend to store sensitive information in db. In your case of storing passwords, you can use Django techniques to store that information relatively-safely such as correctly hashing passwords via pbkdf function (e.g. pbkdf or bcrypt, etc). If users will need to download that information, you can always generate the file on the fly for them for download.

---

Some suggestions for uploading files.

I usually assign random filenames to the uploaded files. This way at least its more challenging for the users to guess the filenames to download them. Not very security since this relies on security by obfuscation but its better then nothing. If you need a Django field which does that automatically, you can do that by making `upload_to` a callable (there are also 3rd party libs for doing that such as [`django-auxilium`](http://django-auxilium.readthedocs.org/en/latest/highlights.html#model-fields) although for full disclosure Im the author of that lib).

Now that files are stored with random filenames, you probably never want to provide direct download links to the users for download but instead authenticate them first and then use something like [`X-Accel`](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/x-accel/) in nginx or [`X-Sendfile`](https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/) in Apache to actually serve the file to the user. The idea being that you first authenticate user in Django. Then however instead of Django serving the file, you return a special header which nginx/apache catches which contains a filepath to the file nginx/apache should serve to the user. This way you dont have to waste resources in Django to serve the file however you still get the advantage of being able to authenticate the request. There are a number of [3rd party apps](https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/file-streaming/) for doing that as well.

Finally to protect users from downloading the media files you can use nginx (and I imagine apache) by restricting certain parts of the media folder:

```
location /media/protected {
  internal;
  alias /var/www/files;
}
```

In this case nginx will refuse direct user requests to `/media/protected` and will only allow to serve those files via `X-Accel-Redirect` header sent by Django. Then all you have to configure in Django is to store files in that path to make them protected:

```
models.FileField(upload_to='protected/myfiles')
```

Comment: I usually store protected files outside of `MEDIA_ROOT`, instead of in a subdirectory. That reduces the risk of accidentally exposing the files because of a misconfiguration, i.e. security by default.

Comment: @knbk do you use custom storage for storing those media files?

Comment: I use a `FileSystemStorage` with a custom location.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for a solution to serve files only to authorized users and came across this post. I think it it is top google result for "django storing and providing secure files"

As the answer is rather old I wanted to share my finding:
django-private-storage (https://pypi.org/project/django-private-storage/) seems to be a good solution to this problem.